# Determining the Entry Point for Incoming Requests in Express.js Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

In my Node.js Express server, I'm trying to pinpoint the exact location where incoming requests are initially processed. I've attempted to log the request object, but I'm struggling to identify the precise entry point within my codebase where requests are first handled upon arrival from the client. Could someone provide insight into which part of the code or which specific line is executed first when a request is received by the Express server?

I've explored logging the request object but haven't been able to trace it back to the initial entry point.
My goal is to better understand the request lifecycle within Express.js and locate the primary handler for incoming requests.
Any tips, code snippets, or explanations clarifying the request processing flow would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We would have to see your code to advise you.  All `app.use()` and other `app.xxx()` calls in Express register request handlers and they are registered in the order the initialization code executes.  Each one of those can register to see every incoming request (common for middleware handlers) or just certain requests that match some path (common for endpoint handlers).  Express will get the incoming request first and then route it to the first request handler that was registered that matches the incoming request.

Comment: What particular problem are you trying to solve?  Your question right now just kind of sounds like a general request for education on how Express works which is not a very  specific question and thus kind of hard to answer in a typical stackoverflow answer (too general, too broad, requires a chapter in a book to answer).